# Как сгенерировать иконочный шрифт и стили CSS?

Tags: css, шрифты, fontawesome, иконки

Имеется папка с SVG картинками. Каким образом можно получить набор CSS стилей, чтобы использовать их аналогичным образом как и иконки из широкораспространённого FontAwesome? Примерно так:

```html
<i class="p p-icon"></i>
```

Здесь `p` - собственный префикс, `icon` - название файла с иконкой.

В репозитории уже упомянутого проекта есть [отдельные каталоги](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/advanced-options/raw-svg/regularf) с такими картинками. А как получается готовый результат в виде .ttf, .eot и .css файлов? Есть какой-то инструмент, или это делается вручную??

Answer (score 3):

https://icomoon.io/app/#/select 
Загружаешь svg иконки 'import icons', затем выбираешь загруженные иконки, просто кликнув по ним, жмешь Generate font - конвертируешь в фонт, и скачиваешь.